how do you select the maximum value accross each row in pandas
Hi have this data frame:
Server     1-Jun   6-Jun   1-jul  Jul-10
ServerA    8        9        5     90
ServerB    100      10      9     90

I need to create another column called maximumval and pick the maximum value from all of the months per Server:
Resulting data frame needs to be like this:
Server     1-Jun   6-Jun   1-jul  Jul-10.  maximumval
ServerA    8        9        5    90       90
ServerB    100      10      9     90       100

I tried this this
df['maximumval'] = df.max(axis=1)

I get this error:
'>=' no supported between instances of 'str' and 'float'

any ideas what does this mean? how do you fix this?

This is due to the "Server" column that contains strings.
Use the numeric_only=True option of max:
df['maximumval'] = df.max(numeric_only=True, axis=1)

Alternatively, use select_dtypes to only keep the numeric columns:
df['maximumval'] = df.select_dtypes('number').max(axis=1)

Output:
    Server  1-Jun  6-Jun  1-jul  Jul-10  maximumval
0  ServerA      8      9      5      90          90
1  ServerB    100     10      9      90         100


If it makes sense, you may want to set the Server column as your index.
df = df.set_index("Server")
df['maximumval'] = df.max(axis=1)

Output:
         1-Jun  6-Jun  1-jul  Jul-10  maximumval
Server
ServerA      8      9      5      90          90
ServerB    100     10      9      90         100

